# CHKDSK from a USB

Tags: hard-drive, boot, chkdsk

I am currently on the GParted Live CD, and it is telling me that I have to run `CHKDSK /f`

I am more that happy to do that, but I cannot boot into windows, and I do not have a Windows Recovery disk handy.

Is there a way that I can get `chkdsk` in GParted without too much effort? If not, is there  a simple way that I can load CHKDSK onto a bootable flash drive?

**Update:**

I now have access to a machine with windows vista, and no admin rights (cannot create a repair disk)

Comment: Win7 ISOs are available for download, and you can easily boot from a DVD/USB and run chkdsk from the Command Prompt.

Comment: @Karan where can I find such images?

Comment: You've been here such a long time, thought you'd know [where](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft). :)

Comment: @Karan still not a mind reader though